# Moving email from Outlook archive into Office 365 account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange, office365

My company is moving to Office 365 from a 3rd party Exchange provider. We've got all of our old email archived and stored locally. I would like to take all of the email that's been archived and move it into the new remote exchange server (hosted by Office 365). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook attach the pst archive and just drag all the email from your archive to your new office365 inbox.